# How do I run two groups of conditions at the same time

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, filter

I am stumped. Here's my dataset `dummy`:

```
        ID  Received_X_after_Y
      <dbl>              <dbl>
    1     1                  1
    2     1                  0
    3     1                  0
    4     2                  1
    5     2                  1
    6     3                  0
    7     3                  0
    8     4                  0
    9     4                  1
```

What I want to return:

```
     ID  Received_X_after_Y
    <dbl>              <dbl>
1     1                  1
4     2                  1
6     3                  0
9     4                  1`
```

What I'd like to do:

1. If `Received_X_after_Y` = 1, then I'd like to keep only this row, and remove other rows that share the same ID despite them returning a value of 0 or 1 on this column.
2. I am happy for the top row that meets the condition to be selected.
3. If the ID only has `Received_X_after_Y` = 0 (i.e. none of its rows have `Received_X_after_Y` = 1), then I'd like to just keep the top row within the same ID group.

```
dummy_one <- dummy %>%
  if(Received_X_after_Y == 1) {
    distinct(dummy, ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
  }
```

That's all I can think for now for the first half of the code but even then I am getting an error:

```
Error in if (.) Received_X_after_Y == "1" else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (.) Received_X_after_Y == "1" else { :
 the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I've tried to use the if...else function but I don't know how to make sure that once the rows that meet condition 1 are selected, that they are then excluded from the second lot of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr` syntax, you can first `group_by` your `ID` column, then use a OR `|` condition in the `filter` function, specifying either `all` values in group equals `0` OR `|` the value is `1`. After that, `slice_head` to only keep the first row of observation.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(all(Received_X_after_Y == 0) | Received_X_after_Y == 1) %>% 
  slice_head() %>% 
  ungroup()
```

---

With `dplyr` version >= 1.1.0, you can simplify the operation by a little bit, where you can specify the traditional `group_by` in the `filter` function itself (`.by` argument).

```
df %>% 
  filter(all(Received_X_after_Y == 0) | Received_X_after_Y == 1, .by = ID) %>% 
  distinct_all() %>% 
  ungroup()
```

---

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     ID Received_X_after_Y
  <int>              <int>
1     1                  1
2     2                  1
3     3                  0
4     4                  1
```

Comment: This is very intuitive, thank you! Teaches me how I can apply this for non numerical variables too.

Answer (score 4):

With `dplyr`, you can use `slice_max()` by groups.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  slice_max(Received_X_after_Y, with_ties = FALSE, by = ID)

#   ID Received_X_after_Y
# 1  1                  1
# 4  2                  1
# 6  3                  0
# 9  4                  1
```

If the `dplyr` version you're using is before `v1.1.0`, you need `group_by(ID)` separately.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_max(Received_X_after_Y, with_ties = FALSE) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

An alternative with `distinct()` like what you have tried:

```r
df %>%
  arrange(ID, desc(Received_X_after_Y)) %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

---

###### Reproducible Data

```r
df <- read.table(text =
"ID Received_X_after_Y
1 1 1
2 1 0
3 1 0
4 2 1
5 2 1
6 3 0
7 3 0
8 4 0
9 4 1")
```

Comment: Elegant solution for my problem- thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
aggregate(.~ID, df, max)

  ID Received_X_after_Y
1  1                  1
2  2                  1
3  3                  0
4  4                  1
```

Comment: Lol nice one… many ways to skin this cat. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One more with `dplyr >= 1.1.0`:

```
df %>% 
  summarise(Received_X_after_Y = max(Received_X_after_Y), .by=ID)

  ID Received_X_after_Y
1  1                  1
2  2                  1
3  3                  0
4  4                  1
```